# Maven 3.5 issue with JDK 9

Tags: maven, java-9

I am using Maven 3.5.0 and JDK 9 build 171. When I tried to compile my project I got an exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project admin: Fatal error compiling: ja-va.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/file/BaseFileObject: com.sun.tools.javac.file.BaseFileObject
```

I added suggested flags to the MAVEN_OPTS but without success:

```
--add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: com.sun.tools access not public anymore see module system...

Comment: Does the  `--permit-illegal-access` or the more recently added version of it `--illegal-access=warn` help here?

Comment: Can you run `mvn` with `-X` option for debug check what is the version of those modules, which are used by the mvn compiler plugin: `org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api`,
`org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-manager`,
`org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-javac:jar`. The version should be 2.8.1.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. The issue appeared because of Lombok library. Upgrading to the latest version resolved this issue.

Comment: try upgrading lombok to latest- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok

Answer (score 5):

Verify Java version used by Maven is correct.

Run `mvn -v` this will show which java version maven is using.

For me, Maven was using Java 15, but my application was intended to run on Java 8. Setting JAVA_HOME to path for jdk8 fix the issue.

Answer (score 4):

My project had a dependency on the Lombok library. Updating the pom.xml to version 1.16.18 allowed the build to complete with warnings:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor to field com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoveredProcs
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading the lombok version to 1.18.0 may fix your issue.

[Check here. They fixed the issue in 1.18.0 version](https://github.com/1and1/snmpman/commit/1813b8d26122fa669e9bd1969b956dc1fc5d7946)

Answer (score 2):

Maven compiler plugin in version 3.6.1 is not suitable. You should use at least 3.6.2 version.